# PHP array reorganize with unique count

Tags: php, arrays, key, exists

I have following array which has ID as index, and some count as value. Ultimate goal is to get total of unique IDs in another array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Team Object
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [countStat] => 25
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Team Object
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [countStat] => 24
                )
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Team Object
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [countStat] => 23
                )
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Team Object
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [countStat] => 23
                )
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Team Object
                (
                    [id] => 5
                    [countStat] => 21
                )
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => Team Object
                (
                    [id] => 3                    
                    [countStat] => 21
                )
        )
    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => Team Object
                (
                    [id] => 5
                    [countStat] => 20
                )
        )
    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => Team Object
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [countStat] => 20
                )
        )
)
```

I want result like below.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Team Object
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [countStat] => 48
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Team Object
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [countStat] => 44
                )
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Team Object
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [countStat] => 44
                )
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Team Object
                (
                    [id] => 5
                    [countStat] => 41
                )
        )
)
```

I has spend few hours working on it but couldn't get solution. Can someone please help ?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you share your code? what exactly have you tried? what is `Team Object`? how can you access the "id" and the "countStat" fields?

Comment: are you getting this array from a mysql query?

Comment: wouldn't this structure be better? Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [countStat] => 48 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [countStat] => 48 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 3 [countStat] => 48 ) ) why do you need the extra layer, are you going to have other arrays in there alongside the 'Team object'?

Comment: @jameson2012 Yes, it is coming from mysql query.

Comment: @jameson2012 It is a good idea to remove that layer and do the calculation, I will try that now.... and yes eventually I have to combine this with other team objects.

Comment: @dWinder, I would love to share the code but other part of code is bit long and complicated,  not sure if I am allowed to do that from project perspective. thanks for asking though

Comment: The just use a sum and group by, such as "Select id, SUM(stats) from yourtable GROUP BY id

Comment: @jameson2012 So this is Goal stat.( head goal, free kick goal, penalty goal, regular goal).... I need to combine all goal stat in one for a single team. In same query I am fetching other stats too where i do not need sum, for specific few stat I need some and other will come as it is.

Comment: in that case you need to provide much more information as how can we help you to access an array when we don't know where the data is coming from.  I'd refer you back to @dWinder , and if as you say you aren't able to give us any of the code then you need to either think of a way to mock up an example of your data, how you get it and what you want to do with it, and what you have tried, or unfortunately you need to work it out for yourself

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to sum team object's countStats for like ids.
I've created a similar data structure, looped through it to form a temporary array that uses the id as a key, with associated amounts (to later sum - mine is amount, yours is countStats).
Then sum those and recreate desired output.

```
<?php

class Team
{
    public $id;
    public $amount;
    public function __construct($id, $amount)
    {
        $this->id     = $id;
        $this->amount = $amount;
    }
}

$input =
[
    [new Team(1, 3)],
    [new Team(1, 4)],
    [new Team(2, 5)],
    [new Team(2, 7)]
];

foreach($input as $subarray)
    $amounts[$subarray[0]->id][]=$subarray[0]->amount;

print_r($amounts);

foreach($amounts as $k => $v)
    $result[] = [new Team($k, array_sum($v))];

print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 7
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Team Object
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [amount] => 7
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Team Object
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [amount] => 12
                )

        )

)
```